# Generally define the process of testing

Tags: testing, quotes

How would you define testing? In the interest of full disclosure, I'm posting this because I already have some answers I like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing is any process by which it is verified that each feature (user story, requirement...) has been developed as required, or not.

Answer (score 3):

“Testing is the process of comparing the invisible to the ambiguous, so as to avoid the unthinkable happening to the anonymous.”– [James Bach](http://www.satisfice.com/blog)

It sounds funny, but if you parse out each word, it's right on the money.

Comment: I intended to post this quote. It is very true :-)

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what context of Testing you are referring to.

In the strictest sense of the word, Testing is just double checking that the program does what it is meant to do without error no matter what the user inputs. Also, an Error would be something unexpected. Not all error crash the program.

Answer (score 2):

Some more fun "quotes on quality" [here](http://qcboss.wordpress.com/2008/09/08/quotes-on-quality/). It's a short list, so I'll just post them (from qcboss.wordpress.com):

“An effective way to test code is to exercise it at its natural boundaries” — Brian Kernighan

“Testing is organised skepticism.”– James Bach

“Program testing can be used to show the presence of bugs, but never to show their absence!”– Dijkstra

“Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it.”– Knuth

Software Testers: “Depraved minds, usefully employed.” — Rex Black

Answer (score 2):

Testing grant me :

- the serenity to accept the bug I can not change,
- courage to fix the bug I can change, and
- wisdom to know the difference

(oops, I must have that confused with another pledge...)

Comment: this humorous answer is by no mean disrespectful toward AA members, for whom I have much respect

Answer (score 2):

Testing is the comparison of implementation with intent/expections.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to just test like try this application 
http://www.testalways.com/2010/07/05/find-bugs-and-patterns/

and then describe what you just did. That I would consider defining the process of testing